# Groovy how to push value to array of type long

Tags: java, arrays, groovy

New to groovy so take it easy...
I get an error that there is no push() method for an array of longs

```
def mylongs=[] as long[];
somebject.each{
     //logic to chooose...
     mylongs.push(it.thisisalong);
}
```

So how do I append long values properly. Using

```
 mylongs[mylongs.size()]=it.thisisalong
```

yields out of index bounds exceptions

Comment: Perhaps [this section of the documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_adding_or_removing_elements) will be helpful to you.

Comment: If someone gave a satisfactory answer, would you mind assigning it?

Answer (score 6):

First let me address your second question, and the larger difference between Arrays and Lists in the JVM:

Arrays, and lists in Java are 0-based, meaning that the first element can be found in a[0], and the last element, in a[a.size()-1]. Element a[a.size()] exceeds the bounds of your array, and that is what your exception tells you.

In groovy you can use a.last(), if you want to pick up the last element of an array/list, in my opinion it is more readable and self-explanatory.

If you cast your mylongs into an array before populating it, then you have fixed the size of the array, and you can push no more objects into it. If your array has variable size, then you need to use a List.

```
List<Long> a=[]

a << 1 as long
a << 2 as long
```

etc

When you need to convert it back to an array, you can do this:

```
a as long[]
```

Now to the answer of the first question, the others pretty much gave you a valid answer, but in groovy style, i'd write (providing that somebject is a collection of some type):

```
def mylongs= somebject.collect{ it.thisisalong } as long[]
```

But pushing an element into an List and be done like this, in groovy style:

```
myLongs << 4
```

You cannot append values into an array, it has a fixed size.

Comment: Either it can be like: `ArrayList<Long> ...` like Java's which will be less Groovy

Comment: List<Long> a=[] actually produces an ArrayList<Long>. List<Long> is only an interface

Answer (score 2):

```
mylongs = someobject*.thisisalong as long[]
```

should do. `*.` is [spread operator in groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_spread_operator).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this.

```
 def mylongs=[];
 somebject.each{
      //logic to chooose...
      mylongs.add(it.thisisalong as long);
 }
```

Comment: everytime someons uses `each` to `collect` data, a kitten dies!

Comment: Ha ha. but how else would you pass a list of values through conditionals without a loop?

Comment: @user2782001 filter aka findAll in groovy

Comment: I'm new to groovy, but wouldn't findAll just be a wrapper which passes conditions for a loop evaluation?

Comment: and so is `each`.  why not use a `for` then instead?  groovy allows you to write "java" code just fine.  but if there is a shortcut i use it. `someobject.findAll{ it.thecond>5 }*.thisisalong` to me is more concise than any for/if loop one ever can write.